# Inequality about External path length

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, binary-trees, binary-search

First of all LPL is Leaf path length & IPL is internal path length. While i was studying algorithm analysis for average complexity of binary search , i saw that inequality. Before that, i proved by induction for any full binary tree T, LPL(T) = IPL(T) + 2*I where I is the number of internal nodes . Now after that i tried to understand that inequality but i could not understand the idea.

Some definitions(a bit informal):
external path length is the same thing with leaf path length. Leaf path length is the sum of depths of the all leaf lengths, assuming root node has 0 depth. Internal path length is the sum of the all depths of internal nodes. Internal node is a node that has child. In question tree is full binary tree thus all internal nodes have 2 children.

[image: Inequality]

Comment: I can't tell what your question is.  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question in the body of your post.  Normally a question ends with a "?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varphi(L) = L \log_2 L$ and notice that $\varphi$ is a convex function. Let $T$ be a tree with $L$ leaves. You can show by induction on $L$ that $LPL(T) \ge \varphi(L)$.

If $L = 1$, then $LPL(T)=0 = \varphi(1)$.

If $L>1$ then let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be the left and right subtrees of the root and call $L_i$ the number of leaves of $T_i$. Using the induction hypothesis on $L_1$ and $L_2$:
$$
\begin{align*}
LPL(T) &= L + LPL(T_1) + LPL(T_2)  \ge L + \varphi(L_1) + \varphi(L_2) \\ &\ge L + 2\varphi\left(\frac{L_1+L_2}{2}\right)  
= L + 2 \varphi\left(\frac{L}{2}\right) \\
&= L + 2 \frac{L}{2} \log \frac{L}{2} = L + L(\log L - 1) = \varphi(L).
\end{align*}
$$

This completes the proof by induction. Now let $L' = 2^{\lfloor \log L \rfloor}$ and consider the tree $T'$ obtained from $T$ by iteratively deleting two maximally deep leaves that are siblings until the number of leftover leaves is exactly $L'$.
Notice that there will be $L-L'$ iterations, that the depth $d$ of the two leaves deleted by each iteration will be at least $1+\log L'$, and that such deletion decreases the value of LPL by at least $2d-(d-1)=d+1 = 2+ \log L'$.
Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
LPL(T) &\ge  LPL(T') + 2(L-L') + (L-L') \log L' \\
&\ge  \varphi(L') + 2(L-L') + (L-L') \log L' \\
&= L' \log L' + 2(L-L')  + (L-L') \log L' \\
&= L \log L' + 2(L-L') \\
&=  L \lfloor \log L \rfloor + 2(L - 2^{\lfloor \log L \rfloor} ).
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and effort  , appreciated.